# Calculating partial derivatives python

Tags: python, derivative, sigmoid

I am little bit confused how to calculate the partial derivatives of sigmoid function in python. Since in general we can calculate that by using the given code:
Example: f(x,y) = x4 + x * y4
w.r.t x. would be then :

```
import sympy as sym
 
#Derivatives of multivariable function
 
x , y = sym.symbols('x y')
f = x**4+x*y**4
 
#Differentiating partially w.r.t x
derivative_f = f.diff(x)
derivative_f
```

how would the code work for partial derivatives of this then:
[image: multivariate function]

I tried to sub to the same function but I think I am doing something incorrectly

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out around code that you are writing. Your question, instead, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Can someone point me towards a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I think you could find help by moving this question to https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.